# can not get current user after page refresh in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i'm trying to display Logged in User name .
After login i can get user name but once i refresh page it is undefined .

My code :

```
<p>{{currentUser.profile.full_name}}</p>
```

i try other way too

**blaze Side**

{{currentUser}}

**js**

```
Template.main.helpers({
  "currentUser": function() {
     if (Meteor.user())
         return Meteor.user().profile.full_name;
   }
});
```

after login i can get name but i can not get name after refresh page.

So, what is solution for get name if i refresh page in Meteor blaze ?

Comment: are you still logged in after a page refresh? if you go to the browser console and print out Meteor.userId(), does it have a value? there's nothing wrong w/ your original html that i can see.

Comment: Please mention which login functionality you used? Google or fb or LinkedIn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  Template.Default.onCreated(function() {
    this.user = Meteor.user();
  });


  Template.main.helpers({
    currentUser: function() {
      var user = Template.instance().user;
      if (user) {
         return user.profile.full_name;
      }
  });
```

Also make sure that `profile.full_name` exists;